# Renaming a devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I don't really have a code example for this question. I have a rails app with a devise model called User. I decided that that isn't a very good name for that model and I want to change it to BusinessOwner. What's the best way to go about this? Should I create a migration to change the table and indexes, then manually replace user with busiess owner in my app? Will I be able to change 'authenticate_user!' to 'authenticate_business_owner!' ? Or should I create a new devise model with the devise generator and just delete the old table and model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new model with `rails g devise BusinessOwner` then edit the migration file with any customizations you like. I am assuming you don't have any data to move over at this point?

Comment: I ended up creating a new devise model and replacing all the users with business_owners in my app. There were a lot of places, controllers, views, tests, associations in other models. It seems like that's the only way to do it. It took an hour or so.